# How to set a constant color scale with Shiny + gvisGeoChart?

Tags: r, google-visualization, shiny, ggvis, googlevis

I was able to create an interactive geoChart using the scripts below though, the problem is that the scale to distinguish map color changes each day. My data set is a year worth of daily stats by every state in US.

For instance, for day 1, the scale takes min and max value of that particular day. But I'm trying to change the scripts so that **the scale becomes constant for any given day (and shows min and max of the whole year)**.

Can anyone please advice how to do this? Thank you!

global.R

```
library(shiny)
states <- read.csv("queries_geo.csv")
states$StartDate <- as.Date(states$StartDate, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("PlayStation4 Search Volume Trend by States"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("StartDate", "Quarter",
              min = min(states$StartDate), 
              max = max(states$StartDate),
              value = min(states$StartDate),
              step = 1,
              animate = TRUE)),

mainPanel(
  htmlOutput ("GeoStates")
))))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(googleVis)

shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

  querydate <- reactive({
    states_new <- states %>%
      filter(StartDate == input$StartDate) %>%
      select(Geo,Queries) %>%
      arrange(Geo)})

  output$GeoStates <- renderGvis ({
    GeoStates <- gvisGeoChart(querydate(), 
                              "Geo", #locationvar
                              "Queries", # colorvar
                              options = list(region = "US",
                                            displayMode = "regions",
                                            resolution = "provinces",
                                            sizeAxis.maxValue = max(states$Queries),
                                            sizeAxis.minValue = min(states$Queries),
                                            width = 600, 
                                            height = 400)
                              )})})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. I'm posting my solution so that hopefully it saves someone else time in the future! Thank you for reading my question!

**global.R** => *no change in this part*

```
library(shiny)
states <- read.csv ("queries_geo.csv")
states$StartDate <- as.Date(states$StartDate, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

**ui.R** => *significant changes happened in this part. Instead of creating a map chart in server.R and htmlOutput in ui.R, this code creates a map in ui.R. This way, the map scale stays constant and the animation works smoothly. server.R just feeds reactive data to the map chart in ui.R.*

```
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)
library(googleCharts)

min_query <- min(states$Queries)
max_query <- max(states$Queries)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  # This line loads the Google Charts JS library
  googleChartsInit(),

  # https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart
  googleGeoChart("GeoStates",
                 width = 1000,
                 height = 600,
                 options = list(
                   fontSize = 13,
                   region = "US",
                   displayMode = "regions",
                   resolution = "provinces",
                   colorAxis = list(
                     maxValue = round(max_query, -3),
                     minValue = round(min_query, -1)
                   ))),

  fluidRow(
    shiny::column(4, offset = 4,
    sliderInput("StartDate",
                "StartDate",
                min = min(states$StartDate), 
                max = max(states$StartDate),
                value = min(states$StartDate),
                step = 60,
                animate = TRUE)
  ))))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(googleVis)

shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

  querydate <- reactive({
    states_new <- states %>%
      filter(StartDate == input$StartDate) %>%
      select(Geo,Queries) %>%
      arrange(Geo)
    })

  output$GeoStates <- reactive({
    list(
      data = googleDataTable(querydate())
    )})})
```